# Identifying joint/conditional probability from question

Tags: probability, self-study

I am trying to solve a basic probability question. This problem is an example of the law of total probability. Here is the problem with its solution.

[image: Test]

---

I interpreted the first line of the question as $P(C \cap M) = 0.07$ and $P(C \cap F) = 0.004$.

But from the solution, it appears the first line meant conditional probability, not a joint probability.

My question is, how am I supposed to understand that the statement meant conditional and not joint probability? Also, is the question poorly written?

Comment: I think it's written clearly. What do you think it was conditioned on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sentence "7% of men ... are colorblind." means "Among men, 7% are colorblind." or in symbols, $P(C|M) = 0.07.$ By contrast, $P(M\cap C) = 3.43\%$ ought to go into English as "In the US population 3.43% are colorblind men."

However, too many imprecise and/or innumerate writers are not careful to distinguish between $|$ and $\cap.$ For example, in accounts of medical screening tests the terminology "false positive" has come to be used about equally often as either "Positive test and not infected: in the population" or "Positive test among those not infected", conflating probabilities $P(+\cap D^c)$ and $P(+|D^c).$

It has come to the point that "false positive" has become either meaningless, or a puzzle to be solved before reading further. In my own writing, I have decided to use "false positive" and "false negative" only
if accompanied by a correct mathematical expression in the same immediate field of view.

*Note:* For a long time, *Wikipedia* had a lengthy, excellent, and technically meticulous article on screening tests; but it got replaced by a more popularized, and less precise, article. In sequence, various
different pages have followed under the same header. (I have not checked the current
version before writing this.)

Comment: I think it could be even worse, with false positive also perhaps being used to mean $P(D^c\vert +)$. (The $^c$ denotes the complement of people who have the disease, so people who don’t have the disease.)

Comment: @BruceET When said "colorblind man" - I am interpreting it as men that are colorblind which is conditional distribution. This is very confusing. I am going to assume if the sentence contains `and` then it's joint distribution otherwise it's conditional.

Comment: Of course you can interpret "colorblind man" anyway you like, but in English "a person who is colorblind and male" seems very awkward and one would think it strange. Phrases such as "beautiful actress" and "chocolate ice cream" are readily understood as indicating intersections of characteristics. Conditioning is not so frequent, but are easily handled: "of the women I know, she's one of the few psychologists" or "German shepherds are an especially loyal breed of dog."

Comment: I see - I guess I will need more practice. Thank you!